# Can time speed up? If so how can you do it?

Tags: special-relativity, time

Einstein said that by traveling about the speed of light time slows down so it's only natural to think the opposite would speed up time but it does so how does it work.

Comment: Ahhhh, but this question implies that there is an absolute measure of time. But if time is relative, slowing it down for everyone else is the same as speed it up for you...even if it means you have to stick the rest of the universe on a spaceship or near a black hole. But the reason it's not obvious how to speed things up is probably because most things move so slow spatially already through space-time that it's difficult to go any slower and make meaningful changes in the passage of time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How fast can time flow? A question of time dilation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66149/)

Comment: It's unlucky that we happen to live on a rather small planet.  If we lived on a huge planet with very strong gravity, or if we lived on a planet that circled very close to a huge black hole with extremely strong gravity, then to speed up time all you would need to do is move away to a smaller planet or a planet far from the black hole.  But since the rate of time on earth is very close to the rate of time in remote space, any time change would be extremely small.  You could move to the moon.  Time runs faster on the moon than on earth, but only by an infinitesimal amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest time between two events is always measured by the observers for which those events are in the same place - that is, the same displacement vector to the observer.

So, you always measure the shortest time between two events that happen to you, because wherever you go, there you are.

However, you can measure a shorter time between two events distant from each other by boosting into a frame for which those two events are closer together in space.

For instance:

A train with a clock on the side of it drives past you. Each time the clock on the train ticks, the train has moved relative to you. If you boost into the train's frame (you get in your car and match the train's velocity vector), now each time the clock on the train ticks, the train is in the same place relative to you. Thus you have (very very slightly) reduced the time you measure between ticks of the train's clock.